# Given $f^2(x)+g^2(x)+h^2(x)\leq9$ and $U(x)=3f(x)+4g(x)+10h(x)$.Find the maximum value of $U(x)$

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Given $f^2(x)+g^2(x)+h^2(x)\leq9$ and $U(x)=3f(x)+4g(x)+10h(x)$,where $f(x),g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous $\forall x\in R$.Find the maximum value of $U(x)$.

---

I tried using AM GM inequality in this question but i could not succeed.This question is given in the vectors section of my book.May be possible,some vectors concept should be applied here.I am not sure about that.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the method of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: The constraint is an inequality,can we still apply Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Yes, imagine that $f(x)$, $g(x)$, and $h(x)$ are replaced by variables $x,y,z$. Then the given inequality is just a closed sphere of radius 3 in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find the max of $U(x)$ within the sphere and then use the method of Lagrange multipliers on the boundary of the sphere (the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$) and see if the maximum point on the boundary is larger than the maximum you found inside the sphere. If it is, then this value at this boundary point is the maximum. If not, choose the maximum from inside the sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $U(x)=\langle 3,4,10\rangle \cdot\langle f(x),g(x),h(x)\rangle$. Also, recall that for vectors $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $A\cdot B=||A||\,||B||\cos{\theta}$. This implies that $$U(x)=||\langle 3,4,10\rangle ||\,||\langle f(x),g(x),h(x)\rangle ||\cos{\theta}$$
$$=5\sqrt{5}\cos{\theta}\sqrt{f(x)^2+g(x)^2+h(x)^2}$$The maximum of $\cos{\theta}$ occurs when $\theta=0$. Additionally, from the inequality given, the maximum value of $f(x)^2+g(x)^2+h(x)^2$ is 9. Therefore, $$U(x)\leq 5\sqrt{5}(1)\sqrt{9}=15\sqrt{5}$$This maximum is achieved if there exists an x such that $\langle f(x),g(x),h(x)\rangle $ is a multiple of $\langle 3,4,10\rangle $ and $f(x)^2+g(x)^2+h(x)^2=9$.